# Evaluating a String to Determine Variable and Assigning Value in R

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I want to be able to be able to create a new variable in a `data.frame` that is named based on an existing string. So, for example, if the new variable is `Q7A` what I have tried to do is the following:

```
question <- "Q7A"
Q <- parse( text = paste("data$", question, sep = ""))
eval(Q) <- 3
```

What I want this to be interpreted as is:

```
data$Q7A <- 3
```

But I get the following error message: `Error in eval(Q) <- 3 : could not find function "eval<-"`

Comment: Are you doing a course that has this as a problem? Suspiciously similar to the question I link to as possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$`.

```
data[,question] <- 3
```

Always remember `fortune(106)`:

```
If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: Even more eccentric: Computing what data.frame() is assigned to, e.g. using `my.df <- "iris"; question <- "newcol"; answer <- 42; assign(my.df,"$<-"(eval(parse(text=my.df)),question,answer))`... ;)